# ParsleyJS - one error at the time

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

The doc reads : 
http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-ui-overview
One error at the time  - so only one error should be displayed right ?

Why are all being displayed ? / How to make it display only active field error ?

Here's the very basic example :

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
  <input type='text' name='f1' data-parsley-required />
  <input type='text' name='f2' data-parsley-required />  
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gaypjgs/

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one *type* of error, as they are prioritized.